# git setting upstream remote after git review

Tags: git, branch, review

My new orginisation uses git a little strangely and I probably added to this strangeness in a messed up attempt to strange less.

First we are supposed to only do one "git commit" followed by multiple "git commit --amend" until ready to "git review". I genuinely don't see the point of collapsing multiple commits like that, but don't worry that's just me complaining.

Here's my problem: My technical lead asked me to do a review, not to be merged but just so he could examine it. So I created an inspection branch.

```
git checkout -b inspect/rssiswa
git review
```

He had made some comments and changes I would like to merge back into my local branch: inspect/rssiswa

Normally I create a new branch and attempt to push it. It gives me an error message saying how to set the upstream.

```
git push --set-upstream origin inspect/rssiswa
```

But I don't want to push. I want to set upstream so I can "git pull"

TLDR After publishing my private branch with "git review" how do I pull any changes others have made in review. Or is this even possible?

Yes I'm trying to hide my ignorance.

Comment: Note that `git review` is not a standard Git command, so you're using someone's add-on software. You'll need to find out whose, otherwise any answers you get may be for some *other* add-on software.

Answer (score 0):

To set an upstream you don't need to use `git push`.

`git branch` has the `-u|--set-upstream-to` option, and will not try to push or pull a branch from the remote:

```
git branch -u origin/inspect/rssiswa
```

---

To have the remote branch you want to target on your local repo, run `git fetch` -- I'm not privy to how gerrit creates its branches, please read gerrit's documentation or ask your colleagues.